# SVG - smooth morph Paths into each other

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, svg-morphing

I'm currently searching for a solution to morph two or more paths into each other, to create a smooth pinch2Zoom animation. Currently I'm working with opacity to blend the two path's into each other:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-13 15 100 100" enable-background="new -13 15 100 100" xml:space="preserve">

 <path fill="#010202" d="M78.5,93.1l0.8,1.4l-24.3,10l-0.4-1.4c0,0-0.8-2.6-3-4.2C49.7,97.4,29.7,81.2,30.2,75
  c0.3-3.2-0.8-5.4-1.6-7c-0.7-1.3-1.3-2.5-0.7-3.7c0.4-0.9,1.3-1.5,2.6-1.7c1.8-0.3,4.8,0.3,6.8,2.5c1.7,1.8,2.8,4.8,3.9,7.7
  c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.4,1,1.8c2.4,2.9,4.2,2.6,6,0.8c1.9-1.9,1.6-13.6-0.8-15c-1.8-1-4-1-6.8-1.9c-2.9-0.9-6.1-1.7-5.9-5.2
  c0.3-1.6,0.7-2.4,2.8-3.2c4.7-1.8,14.9-2.2,19.5,2.5c1.2,1.2,2.2,1.8,2.8,3.1c0.7-0.4,2.3-1.1,3.4-1.1c3.8,0,14.4,16.8,14.5,16.9
  c1.4,2.6-0.3,12.5-0.9,15.5C76.5,89.1,78.5,93.1,78.5,93.1z M56.6,100.9l18.8-7.8c-0.7-1.6-1.7-4.3-1.2-6.6
  c1.1-5.7,1.8-12.5,1.2-13.7c-1.7-3.1-10.1-14.7-12.2-15.5c-0.8,0-1.3,0.4-1.6,0.6c0.4,1.2,0.6,2.4,0.9,3.4c0.3,1.4,0.6,2.6,1,3.6
  c0.3,0.7,0,1.5-0.7,1.8c-0.7,0.3-1.5,0-1.8-0.7c-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.7-1.2-4.2c-0.3-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3.7c0,0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1
  c-0.6-1.6-2-2.8-3.4-4.3c-3.7-3.7-12.8-3.3-16.6-1.8c-1.6,0.6-1.7,1.5-1.7,1.7c-0.1,1.1,1,1.6,4.1,2.6c3.2,1,7.8,0.8,9.6,4.6
  c0.3,0.6,0.9,3.6,0.9,4.6c0.4,8.3-0.2,10.8-4.3,13.2c-3.1,1.2-7.2-0.9-8.8-5.1c-1-2.6-2-5.4-3.3-6.8C34,65.4,32.3,65,31.3,65
  c-0.5,0-0.8,0.1-0.9,0.2c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.6,1.4c0.9,1.8,2.2,4.5,1.9,8.4c-0.4,4.6,15.3,17.5,20.3,21.4
  C55,98,56.6,100.9,56.6,100.9z">
            
        <animate id="animation1" begin="0.8s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze"/>
    
    </path>

 <path style="opacity:0" d="M76.9,87.2c0.5-2.9,2.1-12.7,0.8-15.2c-0.1-0.2-10.6-16.5-14.3-16.5c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.3,0.5c-0.5-2.9-1-6-1.2-8.5
  c-0.4-5.3-1.3-8.5-4.9-8.9c-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-2.1,0.7c-2.1,2-3.3,8.3-2.8,16.2c0.6,12.3-1.1,20.5-3.2,21.3c-1.3,0.5-4-2.2-6.1-4.3
  c-2.1-2.2-4.3-4.4-6.6-5.4c-2.7-1.1-5.5-0.5-7.1,0.5c-1,0.7-1.6,1.6-1.6,2.6c0,1.3,1,2.1,2.1,3.1c1.3,1.1,3.2,2.6,4.3,5.6
  c2.1,5.7,18.3,18.5,20.2,20c2.2,1.6,3,4.1,3,4.1l0.4,1.4l23.7-10l-0.8-1.3C77.9,92.2,76.5,89.2,76.9,87.2z M57.2,100.9
  c-0.6-1.2-1.6-2.8-3.4-4.1C49,93,36.1,82.3,34.5,78.1c-1.3-3.7-3.6-5.5-5.1-6.8c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.1-1c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.8-0.5
  c0.9-0.4,2.6-0.7,4.2,0c1.8,0.7,3.7,2.8,5.7,4.7c3.1,3.2,6,6.2,9,5c5.6-2.3,5.1-18.9,4.9-24c-0.5-8.9,1.2-13.5,2-14.1
  c0.9,0.1,2,0.4,2.4,6.4c0.4,5.9,2.3,15.5,3.9,19.2c0.3,0.7,1.1,1,1.8,0.7c0.7-0.3,1-1.1,0.7-1.8c-0.6-1.3-1.3-3.9-2-6.8
        c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-0.7c2.1,0.8,10.3,12,12,15.1c0.6,1.1-0.1,7.8-1.1,13.4c-0.5,2.3,0.5,4.9,1.2,6.5L57.2,100.9z">

         <animate id="animation2" begin="0.8s" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur="1.3s" fill="freeze"/>
    
    </path>

</svg>
```

But this is just a workaround, and I'm not really finding much on the internet about "real" svg animations, which transform paths into, well other paths...so maybe one of you has an neat idea :) - thx in advance

Comment: this [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/svg-shape-morphing-works/) on svg morphing should get you started

Comment: thx that is a step in the right decision :)

Answer (score 1):

To animate paths you need paths with the same number and types of command. Both paths start with an M but in the first path the second command is an l and in the second path its a c. Your paths are therefore not interpolatable by the UAs SMIL engines.

After you've fixed that you need to put the other path in the to or values attribute of the animate tag of the first path.